# mp4-file vichuploader Symfony 5 mime type validation sometimes blocking good videos

Tags: symfony, validation, mime-types, symfony5, vichuploaderbundle

In a Symfony 5 project using vich uploader for video uploads defining the field like

```
/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="d_video", fileNameProperty="videoName", size="videoSize")
 * @Assert\File(
 *     mimeTypes = {"video/mp4"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Wrong File-Typ - please pick a MP4-Video.",
 *     maxSize = "250M",
 *     maxSizeMessage="Max. video size: 250MB. "
 * )
 *
 *
 * @var File|null
 */
private $videoFile;
```

and the form field like

```
$builder->add( 'videoFile', VichFileType::class, [
    'label' => 'Your Video',
    'required' => false,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'download_uri' => true,
    'download_label' => false,
    'asset_helper' => false,
] );
```

I get the mime type is wrong error message in the frontend when picking mp4-video files - but only sometimes. I have two test videos - one uploads without problems and one triggers the validation to fail.

According to VLC-Player both videos have the exact same Codec which is

```
Stream 0 - Type: Video
    Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
Stream 1 - Type: Audio
    Codec: MPEG AAC (Audio) (mp4a)
```

Both videos are smaller then 20MB.

I tried to set the assert mime type condition to all available video formats found at
https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#video

But that didn't change the error.
I am not sure on where to look why the validation fails or what to configure to make it work.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Setting a wildcard mimetype should accept all video formats `video/*` instead of having to specify all of them manually. As for debugging the issue you could run some tests using the [mime component](https://github.com/symfony/mime/blob/27227395707c15ddb9c29239d2745d6dd0512bb8/FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php#L47) directly.

Comment: @msg Thanks for that idea - turns out that the mime type is evaluated to be "audio/mp4" at the video that fails but "video/mp4" on the working one. Now... Any idea why that is so? I suppose it's not that sensible to accept "audio/mp4" in a video formfield... is it?

Comment: Maybe because of the container format (the file extension), but can't tell for sure. Maybe [other guesser](https://github.com/symfony/mime/blob/27227395707c15ddb9c29239d2745d6dd0512bb8/FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser.php) returns the correct type? (if available). You could even try to implement your own guesser based on [some library](https://github.com/wapmorgan/MediaFile)?

Comment: Unfortunately FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser is not available. For now I just allowed audio/mp4 as well. It's not that clean but works (production must run...). Any ideas if/how I can determine if the video in question is somehow wrongly encoded or sth? I don't want to figure that out programmaticaly but with a tool or sth to inspect that special video - I might be able to make sure further videos are encoded better...

Comment: No, sorry, if VLC detects it correctly, my only guess is that php's fileinfo is a bit naive on how it detects file content. As I said, maybe it relies only on the file extension / file format (you haven't said if both are the same, besides codec), outdated mimemagic or maybe it mis-identifies files based on the stream order. You can try some of [these tools](https://www.fourcc.org/identifier/) but as for php, maybe a media-specific library or other external tool.